# Find objects with timestamp in a recurring time range

Tags: database, django, django-models, django-queryset

Is it possible to do a QuerySet filter that returns object form a specified, recurring time span?

For example, given a start and an end date a few days apart, I would like to be able to find:

- Get all objects with timestamp between 2pm and 7pm for every day between start and end
- Get all objects with timestamp between 1am and 8am for every day that is either a saturday or a sunday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOT TESTED**

For the first case, assuming MyModel and your timestamp is called date you can do:

```
import datetime

start_date = datetime.date(2012,7,1)
end_date = datetime.date(2012,7,16)
start_time = datetime.time(14,0)
end_time = datetime.time(19,0)
date_range = end_date - start_date

range_list = None
for days in xrange(date_range.days):
    d = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days)
    if range_list is None:
        range_list = Q(date__range = (datetime.datetime.combine(d, start_time), datetime.datetime.combine(d, end_time)))
    else:
        range_list = range_list|Q(date__range = (datetime.datetime.combine(d, start_time), datetime.datetime.combine(d, end_time)))


MyModel.objects.filter(range_list)
```